# Flutter IOS Firebase Crashlytics Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I am not sure what causes this error? I've been trying to work it out for days. Any suggestions?

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x186a7186c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19ba8dc50 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x186977000 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource addManagedSourceForIdentifier:user:]
3  Foundation                     0x187d0b91c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  Flutter                        0x1051f8868 (Missing)
5  Flutter                        0x1051f560c (Missing)
6  Flutter                        0x104ef2028 (Missing)
7  Flutter                        0x10520e540 (Missing)
8  Flutter                        0x1051aa7a8 (Missing)
9  Flutter                        0x1051ac608 (Missing)
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1869edfa0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1869edba0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1869ecffc __CFRunLoopDoTimers
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1869e6ee4 __CFRunLoopRun
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1869e621c CFRunLoopRunSpecific
15 GraphicsServices               0x19e5b3784 GSEventRunModal
16 UIKitCore                      0x189426ee8 -[UIApplication _run]
17 UIKitCore                      0x18942c75c UIApplicationMain
18 MYAPP                          0x1005b1b0c main + 7 (AppDelegate.swift:7)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x1866a66b0 start
```